# WPF MVVM communicate between views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Lets assume I have a button in View A which should trigger functionality of View B. How is this preferably done? I could use the Mediator but I prefer to avoid it and mainly use it for communication between viewmodels where there is absolutely no other way.

Here is a thought of mine:

[image]

So basically we have an interceptor class that handles communication between multiple views. The view doesnt know about the other views. The interceptor acts as a messenger between them.

Is this ok in terms of thinking in MVVM?

Comment: What is the difference between your interceptor and a mediator or a messenger?

Comment: @mm8 my mediator contains static classes and properties this one doesnt. The interceptor is only responsible for a certain feature where the mediator is a the global for communication between the classes of the different features.

Comment: Static classes and properties? And these do what?

Comment: You are describing the mediator pattern.

Comment: @mm8 the classic mediator that I use simply registers the callbacks of classes so that it can be called statically from other classes. It is used globally.

Comment: If your ViewModels are related to each other, such as parent / child, it is perfectly acceptable for one ViewModel to have a reference to the other.  They can then directly call functionality.  If they are disconnected, you would need to use some kind of message passing system, as others have described.

Comment: @BradleyUffner indeed they belong to the same "feature" so also reside in the same namespace

Comment: @BradleyUffner would you treat the Interceptor as a controller or where does it fit inside MVVM?

Comment: In my library, there are a bunch of different "services" that can be configured at application startup.  Every bindable object inherits from `ViewModel`, and has access to these services (as well as the `ServiceManager` through read-only properties.  So you can just do something like this in any ViewModel `this.Messenger.Send(new SomeMessageClassWithData())`, then any other component of the system that registered for that message will receive an event, and can act on the data.  I'm sure all the other MVVM libraries out there have similar systems, even if implemented differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most MVVM frameworks contains a mediator of some kind for this purpose.

In `MvvmLight` it is called `Messenger` and in `Prism` it is called `EventAggregator`. For example.

And the mediator can be used to communicate between any two components, be it a view or a view model, in a loosely coupled way.

So you are basically describing the mediator pattern here. Don't reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: I thought a mediator is just a static class floating around waiting for other classes to store  and call some delegates inside a dictionary. Its the "static" part that got me to dislike it.

Comment: So basically my interceptor is also a Mediator then just not static.

Comment: Yes, your "interceptor" is basically a mediator.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a static class, there are lots of different ways it could be implemented.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I assume static then only makes sense if I want to communicate disconnected systems right. I really did learn a lot now.

Comment: Do you think interceptor as a name fits? :D kinda sounds cool

Comment: It you could have it as a regular class that is instantiated once in the base view model class, in a static *field*, and exposed as a read-only property. That's how I handle it in my mvvm library.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I got a Router class that is responsible for glewing everything together. It also handles dependencies. I will inject the messenger in the viewmodels as it makes more sense since i use Command to trigger events etc.